# Javascript: Creating and Calling Dynamic Variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that contains 3 questions. I have started by creating 3 variables (ex: var q1 = "question here") and I have a function that randomly picks a number between 1 and 3 and chooses that question (var question = "q" + rand;) but if I want to reference this variable called question to output the question in HTML (ex: document.getElement.Id("output").innerHTML += question;) how would I do so?

Here is my code:

```js
// Questions List
        var q1 = " Question 1 here"
        var q2 = "Question 2 here"
        var q3 = "Question 3 here"

  // Randomly generate a question and then output it
        var randy = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
        var question = "q" + randy;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += question;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically the script will choose a question from 1 to 20 and output it to my HTML div tag.

Sorry if this isn't clear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables, use an array.

Comment: had you have a look to [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/)?

Comment: User array or object of questions and access them by using keys.

Comment: Why not have the questions written in html and show them or hide them based on the random selection? This seems more straightforward, but either way you need a way to select the question you want by using JSON or other data structures as the way you are defining the variable won't work to select the question you want

Comment: Okay, I used an array it worked. Thanks.